# "Operator is not overloaded" when checking for a byte in an array of bytes

Tags: arrays, operators, pascal, freepascal

I have an array[0..2] of byte. I need to check if a byte is in that array or not. However, when using `if ($52 in byteArray) then`, I run into the error "Operator is not overloaded". I've tried setting an additional variable as a byte and then using that in the statement, but still get the error. Here's an incredibly simple program showing this:

```
program overloaded;

var
  byteArray: array[0..2] of Byte;

begin
  byteArray[0] := $00;
  byteArray[1] := $69;
  byteArray[2] := $52;

  if ($52 in byteArray) then
    writeLn('We will not get to this point');
end.
```

This will fail to compile with the above error in FPC 3.0.2.

Comment: That's to be expected. You need to loop over the array.

Answer (score 0):

You have two alternatives, overloading the operator or using for.

```pascal
program ByteArrayIteration;
var
  ByteArray: array[0..2] of Byte = ($00, $69, $52);
  SomeByte : Byte = $52;
begin
  for SomeByte in byteArray do
    if SomeByte =  $52 then
    begin
      WriteLn('We will get to this point');
      Break;
    end;
end.
```

And the overload alternative:

```pascal
program OverloadInOperator;

uses SysUtils;

operator in(const A: Byte; const B: TBytes): Boolean;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := True;
  for i := Low(B) to High(B) do if A = B[i] then Exit;
  Result := False;
end;

var
  Bytes : TBytes;
  AByte : Byte = $52;
begin
  Bytes := TBytes.Create($41, $52, $90);
  if AByte in Bytes then WriteLn('Done');
end.
```

If your use case is limited to 255 items per array, consider using sets instead.

```pascal
program SetOfByte;
var
  Bytes : set of Byte = [$41, $52, $90];
  AByte : Byte = $52;
begin
  if AByte in Bytes then WriteLn('Done');
end.
```